# TypeError: is not a function in Node.js after reading a copied object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of objects instantiated in a class that have a getAccounts() function:
`this.keys[j].getAccounts()`

In the parent process, the function of objects works correctly.
These objects are copied in turn into another object that will be passed to processes forked later, i.e. in the result object:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= number; i++) {

    result[i] = {
        nAccs: this.nAccs,
        keys: this.keys,
        address: this.accAddress
    };
```

The result object is then read by the forked processes (which is called args in child processes):

```
this.nAccs = args.nAccs
for (let key = 0; key < args.nAccs; key++) {
    this.keys[key] = args.keys[key]
    this.accAddress[key] = args.address[key]
}
```

the objects are read correctly and correspond to those created in the parent process (for example the strings of the accAddress object correspond to those created previously), but if I then try to invoke a function on the objects just read in child processes by doing:

`this.keys[x].getAccounts()`

I have an error like:
`TypeError: this.keys[x].getAccounts is not a function`
I have the feeling that in the transfer some properties of the object are lost how could this be done?

EDIT: The passing of data between the process and the child process is done at the moment of the fork by inputting the arguments to the `child_process.fork()` function of Node.js. However this step is done internally to an NPM package that I am using as a base for my application, so I would not want to modify it.

Comment: Functions are not serializable so they are lost. How do you send the data between processes?

Comment: As I specified in the edit this step is done internally to an NPM package that I would not want to modify. Is there another way? I had thought of something like creating an object of the type I need and saving the prototype and then changing its values but I'm not sure ...